# How to Export Grape City Active Report 11 Section report Code based to Excel

Tags: excel, activereports, grapecity

I want to export my report which is a section Report (Code based ) in Excel.
I am using Asp Vb.net and Grapecity for my report based website.
On a button click, I call my report or generate the report and display it on the web viewer type "AcrobatReader". from that viewer I can download the report in PDF. in order to generate the report in Excel format I have used a button click and the following code.

```
 Response.ContentType = "application/xls"
                Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=LPO.xls")
                Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8
                Dim excelExporter As XlsExport = New XlsExport()
                ''Dim report As PolRegSessionRpt = CType((WebViewer1.Report), PolRegSessionRpt)
                Dim report As SectionReport = TryCast(Me.WebViewer1.Report, SectionReport)
                Dim directorypath As String = Trim(txtExlDwnd.Value)
                If Not Directory.Exists(directorypath) Then
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(directorypath)
                End If
                excelExporter.Export(report.Document, Trim(txtExlDwnd.Value) + "LPO.xls")
                Dim tw As New System.IO.StringWriter()
                Dim hw As New HtmlTextWriter(tw)
                Response.Write(tw.ToString)
                Response.[End]()
```

the above code works fine in local server while I update it in my server-side **"directory path"** 
which I am giving a hard code string as "D:\exceldownload\". 
i want something like user can select the folder where he wants to save the excel document .

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Section Reports, you will need to use the [Excel Export Filter](https://help.grapecity.com/activereports/webhelp/AR11/webframe.html#Excel.html) to export your reports.  You can access the Excel Export filter by adding the reference to GrapeCity.ActiveReports.Export.Excel.v11.dll in your project.  Please refer the export filter sample in the link below:

https://help.grapecity.com/activereports/webhelp/AR11/webframe.html#ExportingReports.html

GrapeCity Support Team

https://www.grapecity.com/support/contact

Comment: If you can share more information about your report and how it works maybe we can help you resolve the issue. https://www.grapecity.com/support/contact

Comment: From my .aspx page, I pass parameters to the section report ( which is in my app_code folder ) using constructor and inside report start I call my database connection and query which gives values in a dataset. and the above result is  appended into a web viewer.

Comment: in my .aspx page am using a web viewer type  " AcrobatReader " . and a normal .aspx button. to export the report in web viewer to import report in excel format.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Dim m_stream As New System.IO.MemoryStream()
                Dim rpt As SectionReport = CType(Me.WebViewer1.Report, SectionReport)
                rpt.Run()
                Dim XlsExport1 As New GrapeCity.ActiveReports.Export.Excel.Section.XlsExport
                XlsExport1.MinColumnWidth = 0.5
                XlsExport1.Export(rpt.Document, m_stream)
                m_stream.Position = 0
                Response.Buffer = True
                Response.ClearContent()
                Response.ClearHeaders()
                Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"

                Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=DebitNoteAndCreditNote.xls")
                Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8
                Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)

                Response.BinaryWrite(m_stream.ToArray())
                HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest()
```

I tried the above code which works fine. and keep in mind that, the button that is using for excel import need not be used for any other trigger.